# How to create an EXE executable with batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to be able to simply run a Windows batch file and have it create a .exe executable.

I know that you can create files with the following script in batch:

```
@echo off
echo This will be in a text file! >> test.txt
echo And this will be the second line! >> test.txt
```

So I was wondering, would be possible to copy the source code of an EXE file and add an "echo" in front of every line, and a " >> test.exe" and the end of every line?

I tried to open the 39KB .exe in Notepad ++, but it was just a bunch of black NUL characters.

So I'm pretty much asking if there's a way to embed files inside batch files? Even an audio file maybe?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27383152/storing-large-file-within-batch-file/27384211#27384211

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here's how it can be done with certutil utility.
In this case it is demonstrated with hard-coded path to whoami.exe which is a builtin command in windows.

First a script that creates the .bat with the embedded .exe :

```
@echo off
certutil -f -encode  %windir%\system32\whoami.exe whoami.b64
echo @echo off >container.bat
echo certutil -decode "%%~f0" whoami.exe>>container.bat
echo call whoami.exe>>container.bat
echo exit /b %%errorlevel%%>>container.bat
type whoami.b64>>container.bat
del whoami.b64
```

For your exe you'll need to change the path to the exe.Then the `container.bat` should look like:

```
@echo off 
certutil -decode "%~f0" whoami.exe
call whoami.exe
exit /b %errorlevel%
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
..base64 encoded content...
...
-----END CERTIFICATE----
```

certutil can encode/decode base64 and hex here base64 is more convenient because it can be embedded into batch thanks to enclosements (`BEGIN CERTIFICATE` and `END CERTIFICATE`) and base64 encoded strings are shorter than hex ones.