# Create executable binaries from Batch or Shell script from Java Programmatically

Tags: java, shell, batch-file, binary, exe

This is not about creating a batch file or executing a batch file from java but creating a binary from them.

I am not very sure about Linux shell scripts but is know that for Windows Batch scripts there are some programs like **Batch to Exe Converter**. But i want to do it programmatically.

Suppose I read the contents of a batch file from a file :

```
public static String loadFile(String filepath) {
    List<String> lines = Collections.emptyList();
    try
    {
       lines =
       Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(filepath), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String s = "";
    for(String line:lines){
        s += line + "\n"
    }
    return s;
}
```

Now i want to convert it to an `exe`.

#### Purpose

My main purpose is to create small executables from those scripts for some small automations which will be used instead of the scripts themselves.

For example:-

I have a `setup.bat` file.

I have my program to automatically generate the batch every time I make any changes(add files) now i also want to have executables along with the scripts.

I also a curious whether a similar thing is possible for Linux shell scripts(creating executables).

Moreover i this is not possible through Java directly can we some how do it using JNI?

Comment: certutil can be utilised in your batch file to create executables. See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30837689/12343998) for an example of how

Comment: The link bellow could be what you are looking for.  You can call the command in your Java program to generate the exe file.  https://superuser.com/questions/868340/how-can-i-convert-a-windows-batch-script-to-a-exe

Comment: @HarryCoder the link 1st is using a gui interface so idk how to call from code(more over iexpress just is a wrapper) second one is using the batch to exe converter itself that is too not use full as i want to do it from my program it self and if it is not possible in java i am ready to go C++ through JNI